# (probably) very simple SQL query needed

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Having a slow day....could use some assistance writing a simple ANSI SQL query.

I have a list of individuals within families (first and last names), and a second table which lists a subset of those individuals. I would like to create a third table which flags every individual within a family if ANY of the individuals are not listed in the second table. The goal is essentially to flag "incomplete" families.

Below is an example of the two input tables, and the desired third table.

[image]

As I said...very simple...having a slow day. Thanks!

Comment: Share table structure, sample data and excepted output. Also, tag which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Hello Rahul. I've added an image which shows the problem. I am using SAS, which utilizes ANSI SQL.

Comment: Why would Diane Thomsom be incomplete?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I assume, since her family members - Barb and Jack are not in the Second table

Comment: Data as pictures is a real problem to code from.

Comment: "Data as pictures is a real problem to code from" ...sorry, that was my first stack overflow post and I didn't see a way to add a table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `left join` and `case` expression:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when t2.first_name is null then 'INCOMPLETE' else 'OK' end) as flag
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.first_name = t2.first_name and t1.last_name = t2.last_name;
```

Of course, this marks "Diane Thomson" as "OK", but I think that is an error in the question.

EDIT:

Oh, I see.  The last name defines the family (that seems like a pretty big assumption).  But you can do this with window functions:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when count(t2.first_name) over (partition by t1.last_name) =
                  count(*) over (partition by t1.last_name)
             then 'OK'
             else 'INCOMPLETE'
        end) as flag
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.first_name = t2.first_name and t1.last_name = t2.last_name;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon- this worked perfectly (but not in SAS)!

Answer (score 0):

That's not simple, at least not in SAS :-)

Standard SQL, when *Windowed Aggregates* are supported:

```
select ft.*,
  -- counts differ when st.first_name is null due to the outer join
  case when count(*) over (partition by ft.last_name)
          = count(st.first_name) over (partition by ft.last_name)
       then 'OK'
       else 'INCOMPLETE'
  end
from first_table as ft
left join second_table as st
  on ft.first_name = st.first_name
 and ft.last_name = ft.last_name
```

Otherwise you need to a standard aggregate and join back:

```
select ft.*, st.flag
from first_table as ft
join 
 (
    select ft.last_name,
      case when count(*) 
              = count(st.first_name)
           then 'OK'
           else 'INCOMPLETE'
      end as flag
    from first_table as ft
    left join second_table as st
      on ft.first_name = st.first_name
     and ft.last_name = st.last_name
    group by ft.last_name
 ) as st
on ft.last_name = st.last_name
```

Comment: @Keith: For SAS I would prefer Tom's solution, which should be more efficient, it's a proprietary version of the *Windowed Aggregate" :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to do in SAS if you want to take advantage of its non-ANSI SQL feature of automatically re-merging aggregate function results back onto detail records.

```
select
   a.first
 , a.last
 , case when 1=max(missing(b.last)) then 'INCOMPLETE' 
        else 'OK' 
   end as flag 
 from table1 a left join table2 b
   on a.last=b.last and a.first=b.first 
 group by 2
 order by 2,1
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used another poster's solution already, but I'll file yours in the "good to know" category!